# Deploying Rails 4 with ricn/rika gem on Heroku - precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I'm running a Rails application using the Rika gem (JRuby wrapper for Apache Tika).  It runs fine locally.  In trying to push it to Heroku, it gets a ways into the deployment until I hit the asset precompile:

...

-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL

-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile

   rake aborted!

   No such file to load -- rika
```

followed by a long string of /tmp/build_8a51... errors.

Precompile works fine on the local machine.

If I try to install the gem via 'heroku run' I get:

$ heroku run gem install rika

Running `gem install rika` attached to terminal... up, run.8601

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError) malformed format string - %)

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I needed to add the ruby version spec line to the Gemfile.  It wasn't necessary on the local machine because I set the version externally.  Heroku needs it though.